# Should I use avif Image rather than webp to have faster website?

Tags: image, webp, avif

Should I use avif Image rather than webp to have faster website ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AVIF has better compression, but slightly less compatibility with some browsers. You can check it on "Can I use?"

So I guess it depends on what you want, I use webp just in case. But both of them has no compatibility with internet explorer, for example.

Hope it helps =)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The file size savings compared to more "legacy" formats is going to be relatively similar for most images, but in general, yes, I'd lean into using it. All major browsers now support it, and there are services out there (like picperf.io) that do the transformation for you and only serve that modern format if a user's browser can support it.